# Debug info when run today extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-today-widget

Got this debug info when debug a today extension app

"host connection < NSXPCConnection: 0x170113560 > connection from pid 53 invalidated"

does anyone know what this means? it shows almost every time when "widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler" called.

Comment: Are you having problems with the extension, or with Xcode debugging it?

Comment: did you find any answers to this question elsewhere?

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this ??

Answer (score 8):

NSXPCConnection API is used to perform interprocess connection between Xcode client and your app on iPhone. So you do not need to worry about this one.

**Link:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html

So there may be 2 reasons that your widget is terminated.

1. You need to call completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNoData); right after your widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler has been called even when the response hasn't been returned.
2. Your app is terminated because of the automatic app termination. It terminates the widgets/apps for 2 reasons:

> a. It terminates apps that are not being used and allowing the
>   reclamation of resources such as memory.
>
> b. It terminates widgets that use too much memory.