# host connection <NSXPCConnection> connection from pid invalidated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-elcapitan, findersync, osx-extensions

I have created finder sync extension and things are working fine on 10.10 OS X but when running on 10.11 , For each new finder window sync extension `- (instancetype)init` method is getting called.

After launching new window I am getting below log in Xcode console

```
15/10/2015 07:51:17.920 pkd[270]: UNINSTALLED:com.MyApp.FinderSync com.MyApp.FinderSync(1.0) 56B1B0FA-1F46-403F-82AA-101E17F551DD /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/FinderSync.appex
15/10/2015 07:51:17.927 pkd[270]: INSTALLED:com.MyApp.FinderSync com.MyApp.FinderSync(1.0) <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fa753d17870> 6E0A9D10-275F-43D4-B8CD-B22923DE879B /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/FinderSync.appex
15/10/2015 07:51:18.016 FinderSync[3237]: host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7f8b22d10d60> connection from pid 260 invalidated
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug info when run today extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011952/debug-info-when-run-today-extension)