# Firebase runTransactionBlock() in iOS share extension

Tags: ios, firebase, ios-extensions

My share extension has the following code as part of the `didSelectPost()` segment:

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    if self.sharedURL != nil {
            // Send data to Firebase
            self.myRootRef.runTransactionBlock({
                (currentData:FMutableData!) in
                var value = currentData.value as? String
                // Getting the current value
                // and checking whether it's null
                if value == nil {
                    value = ""
                }
                // Setting the new value to the clipboard
                // content
                currentData.value = self.sharedURL?.absoluteString

                // Finalizing the transaction
                return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
                }, andCompletionBlock: {
                    // Completion Check
                    (error:NSError!, success:Bool, data:FDataSnapshot!) in
                    print("DEBUG- We're done:\(success) and \(error)")
                }
            )
        }

        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I'm getting the following error at runtime:

```
host connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fb84af2e8c0> connection from pid 16743 invalidated
```

I believe this error is due to the `andCompletionBlock` and related to the following issue: [Debug info when run today extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011952/debug-info-when-run-today-extension)

How can I cleanly and successfully deal with the completion status of the above transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the answer you linked to stated, the `NSXPCConnection` error doesn't matter here.

The issue is that `.runTransactionBlock()` is asynchronous and `.completeRequestReturningItems()` will get called and exit the extension before you ever get a value from your Firebase database.

Try running `.completeRequestReturningItems()` in the `andCompletionBlock`.

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    if self.sharedURL != nil {
            // Send data to Firebase
            self.myRootRef.runTransactionBlock({
                (currentData:FMutableData!) in
                var value = currentData.value as? String
                // Getting the current value
                // and checking whether it's null
                if value == nil {
                    value = ""
                }
                // Setting the new value to the clipboard
                // content
                currentData.value = self.sharedURL?.absoluteString

                // Finalizing the transaction
                return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
                }, andCompletionBlock: {
                    // Completion Check
                    (error:NSError!, success:Bool, data:FDataSnapshot!) in
                            self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            )
        }

}
```

Comment: I am not able to access firebase in my application extension, I am using obj c as language